# Saber Update name in PNR : Error = .ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR

Tags: web-services, api, soap, sabre, sabredav

UpdateReservationRQ APi was working fine to update passsenger name in PNR.
suddenly its returning error

```
<stl15:Warnings>
            <stl15:Warning>
               <stl15:Message>PARTIAL ERROR</stl15:Message>
            </stl15:Warning>
         </stl15:Warnings>
         <stl15:Errors>
            <stl15:Error UpdateId="ID-1">
               <stl15:Code>500900</stl15:Code>
               <stl15:Message>.ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR</stl15:Message>
            </stl15:Error>
         </stl15:Errors>
```

I folowed steps to update name in PNR
1. Create session - SessionCreateRQ
2. Book ticket - EnhancedAirBookRQ
3. Create PNR - PassengerDetailsRQ
4. Read Itenary - TravelItineraryReadRQ
4. Update PNR - UpdateReservationRQ
below is the request for UpdateReservationRQ API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/getres" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns13="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns14="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:or="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_8" xmlns:ota="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:stl1="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_15" xmlns:stl2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <sec:Security xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <sec:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="sec:Base64Binary">${#Project#sectoken}</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
       </sec:Security>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" version="1.0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">99935345999</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">344535</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>AB</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>cpm23432</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service type="OTA">UpdateReservationOperation</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>UpdateReservationRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>608926</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-22T15:49:07Z</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <stl1:UpdateReservationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_15" Version="1.15.0">
            <stl1:RequestType>Stateless</stl1:RequestType>
            <stl1:ReturnOptions IncludeUpdateDetails="true" RetrievePNR="true" />
            <stl1:ReservationUpdateList>
                <stl1:Locator>XPKCGL</stl1:Locator>
                <stl1:CreateDate>2017-05-23</stl1:CreateDate>
                <stl1:ReservationUpdateItem UpdateId="ID-1">
                    <stl1:PassengerNameUpdate op="U">
                        <stl1:TravelerName type="ADT" referenceId="1">
                            <stl1:Given>RamRaj</stl1:Given>
                            <stl1:Surname>Des</stl1:Surname>
                        </stl1:TravelerName>
                        <stl1:NameAssociationTag>
                            <stl1:LastName>DESHMUKH</stl1:LastName>
                            <stl1:FirstName>PRAVEEN</stl1:FirstName>
                            <stl1:NameRefNumber>01.01</stl1:NameRefNumber>
                        </stl1:NameAssociationTag>
                    </stl1:PassengerNameUpdate>
                </stl1:ReservationUpdateItem>
                <stl1:ReceivedFrom>
                    <stl1:AgentName>CPM MBE</stl1:AgentName>
                </stl1:ReceivedFrom>
            </stl1:ReservationUpdateList>
        </stl1:UpdateReservationRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated to identify the issue in request or flow.

Answer (score 0):

From Format Finder (ref pnrfo044):

> - If the electronic ticket has not been issued, please refer to the name change restriction table for the carrier.
> - Once an electronic ticket has been issued in a record, some carriers may allow a name change but others do not. Please refer to the
>     electronic ticket profile for the specific validating carrier for name
>     change restrictions.

You may need to check with the carrier if this is allowed or not.